# What is the final step in Sobel Edge Detection?

Tags: sobel

I've been reading about sobel edge detection, and I'm a little confused as to where the gradient angle comes in.

Assuming a one-channel gray scale image f, after we convolve the Sobel operator g_x and g_y with our original image f, we have two images G_x and G_y. We can use this to calculate |G| = sqrt(G_x^2+G_y^2). We can also use this to calculate theta=arctan(G_y/G_x).

I'm not sure about how to finally calculate the output image here for edge detection. What do we do with |G| and theta?

See Sobel Edge Detection described here
https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci373s1c/PatricesLectures/Edge%20detection-Sobel_2up.pdf

Comment: `|G|` *is* the output image.

Comment: What is the use of theta then?

Comment: But isn't theta describing the angle of image intensity change, and |G| the magnitude?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I wasn't thinking.